# 'Exception ignored in:' when using visa and get_instrument(). Why?

Tags: python, visa, pyvisa

I appear to be getting an 'Exception ignored in:' warning message associated with a visa.ResourceManager.get_instrument() command.  However, I don't understand why I'm getting the warning.

- Note that there is no method or class or anything else associated with the warning.  This makes me think it's happening when my script exits.
- I can make the warning go away by commenting out the "self.rm.get_instrument()" line in my code.

The script from which this code is extracted APPEARS to run properly even with the warning.  However, having a warning I don't understand makes me very nervous.

My code sample is below.  I'm using Python 3.5.1 and Visa 1.8.

Suggestions as to the root cause of the warning would be appreciated.

EDIT: I've added the warning(?) message I'm getting, formatted as code.

```
import visa


class TestEquipment:
    def __init__(self, usbAddress='-1'):
        self.rm = visa.ResourceManager()
        # The following line appears to cause an "Exception ignored in:" warning.
        #   - If I comment-out the line, the warning goes away.
        self.my_instrument = self.rm.get_instrument(usbAddress)


class SpecificInstrument(TestEquipment):
    def __init__(self, usbAddress='-1'):
        TestEquipment.__init__(self, usbAddress=usbAddress)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    usb_address = 'USB0::0x0957::0x9018::MY52350569::INSTR'  # Hard-coded USB address for my borrowed instrument
    FieldSource = SpecificInstrument(usbAddress=usb_address)
```

Here the warning(?) message I'm getting.

```
Exception ignored in: 
Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Please also show the complete message that you get, formatted as code.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel - Duh!  Sorry - I've edited my post to add that information.

Comment: Possibly you could avoid this by explicitly calling `.close()` on your `ResourceManager` before exiting the program, or something similar on the instrument.

Comment: @jasonharper - I tried adding `FieldSource.rm.close()` at the end of my script but I'm still getting the "Exception ignored in:" warning.  Or were you thinking of something different?

Comment: Is there a `.close()` or similar method on the instrument object?  I couldn't find the relevant documentation in a quick search.

Comment: @jasonharper - I tried `FieldSource.close()` but that resulted in `AttributeError: 'SpecificInstrument' object has no attribute 'close'`

Comment: Wait, that's really all the message says? O_O

Comment: @KarlKnechtel - Yep, that's everything.  That's what I find so puzzling - that the message doesn't point to a method or class or something.

Comment: @jasonharper - While neither `FieldSource.rm.close()` nor `FieldSource.close()` solved the problem (see my previous comment), `FieldSource.my_instrument.close()` _did_ eliminate the warning message. If you want to suggest that as the solution, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Based on a suggestion from jasonharper in the comments, the solution was:

```
    FieldSource = SpecificInstrument(usbAddress=usb_address)  # Existing code
    # FieldSource.close()  # Doesn't work.  AttributeError: 'SpecificInstrument' object has no attribute 'close'
    # FieldSource.rm.close()  # No error but still get the "Exception ignored in" warning
    FieldSource.my_instrument.close()  # Success!  No more "Exception ignored in:" warning message!
```

Note that I've included (as comments, for completeness) a couple false starts that didn't result in the solution.